# Looking element on few pages with loop “while” Python, Selenium

Tags: python, loops, selenium, while-loop, global-variables

In my application, I have a table with employees but the table can have more than 1 page with employees. I want to check if the new employee was added (which i created) i want to check that employee in a table and click on it, with Selenium Webdriver Python. The whole idea is check first page if there is no employee with id that I'm looking for than click second page, check there and click on employee, and if there is no click 3rd page etc. I have a function that goes on pages 1 by 1 but it doesn't check that employee which i need on that pages:

```
id = ()
def add_new_employee(driver, first_name, last_name):
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='btnAdd']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#firstName").send_keys(first_name)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#lastName").send_keys(last_name)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#photofile").\
    send_keys(os.path.abspath("cloud-computing-IT.jpg"))
global id
id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#employeeId").get_attribute("value")

def new_employee_added(driver):
global id
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
el = len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text("%s" % id))
while el < 1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % id).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()

        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False

def test_new_employee(driver, first_name="Patrick", last_name="Patterson"):
login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
add_new_employee(driver,first_name, last_name)
new_employee_added(driver)
logout(driver)
```

The problem is in this function:

```
def new_employee_added(driver):
global id
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
el = len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text("%s" % id))
while el < 1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % id).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()

        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
```

loop should try find element  on 1st page, if no go to 2nd and check there, but it seems like it tries find on 1st page then run that piece of loop :

```
 `for i in range(1, 50):
         driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()`
```

and clicking pages not trying to find employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main loop should iterate through all pages and break once you find required `id`. In your code you're trying to find `id` on the first page and if it absent on the first page you just iterate through other pages without executing search for required `id`.

As it's hard to provide you a good solution without actual `html` source below lines are kind of pseudo code:

```
for i in range(1, 50):
    try: 
        # search for required element
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % id).click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # go to next page as there is no required element on current page
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
```

P.S. It seem that there are no reasons to use `global` in your function, you can simply add a parameter to your `new_employee_added` as `new_employee_added(driver, id)` and call it with appropriate value.

P.P.S. Do not use `"id"` as a variable name as `id()` is a Python built-in function

Comment: thanks man, it works, but when i put the text id like ("8513"), can you send example how it should looks using parametrs for my id?

Comment: Just call `new_employee_added(driver, element_id)` as `new_employee_added(driver, "8513")`

Comment: but i'm getting `element_id` from  `def add_new_employee(driver, first_name, last_name):`

Comment: replace `id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#employeeId").get_attribute("value")` in your `add_new_employee` with `return driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#employeeId").get_attribute("value")` and call `new_employee_added` as `new_employee_added(driver, add_new_employee(driver, "James", "Bond"))`